# Insert results of a query on one table into another table

Tags: mysql

In MySQL

I have a table named tasks and I want to select two columns (keyid and proyect). These pairs might repeat so I just want to select one of each combination.

Then I want to insert the result into the columns user and proyect of a second table.

Can anyone provide the syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (name, of, columns) VALUES (SELECT name, of, columns) FROM otherTable)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by one of each but I'm guessing you want something like:

```
INSERT 
  INTO table2 (keyid,proyect)
SELECT DISTINCT keyid, proyect 
  FROM table1
```

Or

```
  INSERT 
    INTO table2 (keyid,proyect)
  SELECT keyid, proyect 
    FROM table1
GROUP BY keyid, proyect
```

Personally I prefer `DISTINCT` in this case, as this is how you have phrased the question.. I tend to use `GROUP BY` only when necessary or when trying to conceptually create groups.

This is very easy to find online;  [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Or perhaps `group by` instead of distinct ?

Comment: Depressingly GROUP BY is probably faster. I wish it wasn't. :-(

Comment: I'd be surprised in this simple case.. but I like surprises!

Comment: You understood right!! Thanks for the modification of my question. I've done it, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate how you would filter the source data. 
You would need to add a WHERE clause at the end of the SELECT to help limit the data.

```
INSERT INTO SecondTable (`keyid`, `proyect`)
SELECT `keyid`, `proyect` FROM `tasks` LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called an `INSERT SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user, proyect) SELECT keyid, proyect FROM tasks LIMIT 1
```

Make sure you list the columns in order on the same order in the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`.
The `LIMIT 1` will just return one record.  You could add a `WHERE` on the `SELECT` or remove/change the limit to fit your needs.